# MySQL complex SQL query showing empty values where a table-column doesn't match

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database: `en_page` and `mwpage`. Both have a `page_title` column. What I want is to select the data where both of the `page_title` values match.

For example

```
SELECT EN.page_title ENP, MW.page_title MWP
FROM en_page AS EN, mwpage AS MW
WHERE EN.page_title =  'Main_Page'
AND MW.page_title =  'Main_Page'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This query works fine and returns following data:

```
ENP |       MWP
Main_Page|  Main_Page
```

But I have an exceptional case. If any of the `table.page_title` values don't match the condition, the query returns no result set. I want it to still return a result set where the table which didn't match should be empty, like the following:

```
ENP |       MWP
Main_Page|
```

I don't know how to do this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT EN.page_title ENP, MW.page_title MWP
FROM 
    en_page AS EN
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mwpage AS MW ON EN.page_title = MW.page_title
WHERE EN.page_title =  'Main_Page'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: perfect!, although it returned null, for empty values but i can work with that!, thanks

Comment: only a single question, what will i need to change if i need to match more tables?

Comment: all depends on how you want to match them. Adding more JOIN's will do the trick. eg. 

FROM 
    en_page AS EN
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mwpage AS MW ON EN.page_title = MW.page_title
    LEFT OUTER JOIN someOtherTable AS other ON EN.page_title = other.page_title

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT EN.page_title ENP, MW.page_title MWP
FROM en_page AS EN, mwpage AS MW
WHERE (EN.page_title =  'Main_Page' OR EN.page_title='')
AND (MW.page_title =  'Main_Page' OR MW.page_title = '')    
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: this didn't work, as there is no empty page_title in any of the tables, and i cant make any either :(

Comment: Try replacing the "=''" with "IS NULL"... for example:  WHERE (EN.page_title = 'Main_Page' OR EN.page_title IS NULL)

Comment: it returned an empty result set, and "joostschouten's" solution works for me, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

To handle the NULL case, just use a `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT EN.page_title ENP, CASE WHEN  MW.page_title IS NULL THEN '' ELSE  MW.page_title END MWP
FROM 
    en_page AS EN
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mwpage AS MW ON EN.page_title = MW.page_title
WHERE EN.page_title =  'Main_Page'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: I'm testing this and it doesn't, are you sure that is a `NULL`? try to change the `THEN ''` in something like `THEN 'test123'` for example.

Comment: it did show NULL in the phpmyadmin, but in the php script, it works as expected!